# ruby: Hello World exercise

Tags: ruby, vim, ubuntu-11.10

I know that my question is not a new one but I will be more specific hopefully to get a specific answer as well.

I am using:

- Ubuntu 11.10 --> (First time in my life though a virtual machine on windows vista)
- Tried to install rvm and Ruby --> (Went successfully but honestly i don't know were they are :D)
- Passed through vim tutorial
- Tried the Hello_World exercise as follows:

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
:! mkdir rubymonk
cd rubymonk
:e hello_world.rb
-------------------------
vim (insert mode)
puts "Hello World"
-------------------------
:wq
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

- Back to the Terminal
- typing: ruby hello_world.rb
- Got the usual error (ruby: No such file or directory -- hello_world.rb (LoadError)

Hopefully I can get an answer from you guys.

Comment: try call the full path to this file, like this: ``ruby ./hello_world.rb`` or like this: ``ruby /usr/<your user name>/path/hello_world.rb``

Comment: Continuing Nicos' inquiry.. Is hello_world.rb in the same directory/folder in which you are running the command `ruby hello_world.rb` from? Also, have you done `rvm install 1.9.3` and `rvm use 1.9.3`? The version number is arbitrary but it's necessary for rvm to work. And you may have to open a new tab or restart terminal for the `ruby` command to be recognized.

Comment: try `ls` if you don't see your file, you're in the wrong directory. You can check where you are with `pwd`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like in vim you created the directory rubymonk, and then cd into it. But that was inside vim, so you need to do the same in your terminal:

```
cd rubymonk
ruby hello_world.rb
```